# select sum of product price for every 1 id productcategory

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-tables

i want to find solution for my query problem. I need to find the SUM of all priceProduct*quantity and separated with each of productcategory. I have already made a query, but it takes longer time to executed it. this is my query,

```
SELECT 
    pb.ProductCategoryID,
    pb.ProductCategoryDescription,
    (SELECT
        SUM((SELECT pd.HPP FROM `price details` pd WHERE pd.ProductID = pdt.ProductID ORDER BY pd.PriceDetailID DESC LIMIT 1)*
                (SELECT StockProductBallance FROM `stock product` sp WHERE sp.ProductID = pdt.ProductID ORDER BY sp.StockProductID DESC LIMIT 1))
        FROM product pdt
        WHERE pdt.ProductCategoryID = pb.ProductCategoryID
    ) AS Total
FROM `product category` pb
GROUP BY pb.ProductCategoryID
```

this my example table

table product:

```
+------+-------+
| id_p | id_pc |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     3 |
|    2 |     4 |
|    3 |     3 |
|    4 |     4 |
+------+-------+
```

table productcategory:

```
+-------+---------+
| id_pc | pc_name |
+-------+---------+
|     3 | new_pc  |
|     4 | old_pc  |
+-------+---------+
```

table price details:

```
+---------------+------+-----+
| PriceDetailID | id_p | hpp |
+---------------+------+-----+
|             1 |    1 | 100 |
|             2 |    1 | 110 |
|             3 |    1 | 120 |
|             4 |    2 | 200 |
|             5 |    2 | 210 |
|             6 |    2 | 220 |
+---------------+------+-----+
```

table stockProduct:

```
+-----------------+------+---------------+
| id_stockProduct | id_p | stockballance |
+-----------------+------+---------------+
|               1 |    1 |            10 |
|               2 |    1 |            11 |
|               3 |    1 |            12 |
|               4 |    2 |            20 |
|               5 |    2 |            21 |
|               6 |    2 |            22 |
+-----------------+------+---------------+
```

Really need your help guys, for better query..

Comment: Here's a good rule-of-thumb: A query with an aggregating function requires a GROUP BY clause. A GROUP BY clause should not be provided unless an aggregating function is present.

Comment: PoductID and PriceDetailID  are primarykey right? I mean they must be indexed